# Using Jquery click code in Magento2

Tags: magento2, jquery

I am needing to track a click on a link in Google Analytics so I am adding the below to the footer of my Magento 2.3 website. I have jquery on the site but for some reason the below cost is not working. I don't see the click in GA nor do I see my message in the console. I am not sure what I am doing incorrect.

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ink-refilling-suggestion").click(function(){
         ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘ Refill Finder’, ‘Click’, 'Refill Finder View');
         console.log('count refill finder click');
    })
});
});
```

Comment: Does console log print or not?

Answer (score 0):

check below code

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', 'ink-refilling-suggestion', function() {
            console.log('here');
        });
    });

});
```